# Plotting three sub plot bar chart with correct labelling

Tags: python, matplotlib

I cannot seem to make the plots work with labels correctly. The plots work in terms of generating three sub plots bar charts. But what I want to label each and every plot (3) with labels `cr_lst`. How do I ensure that I can label each of these bars with `cr_lst` and on each bar.

```
plt.figure(0)
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
cr_lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
A_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B_lst = [2, 2, 6, 7]
A_lst = [8, 8, 6, 7]
ind = np.arange(len(A_lst))  # the x locations for the groups
f, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True)
axarr[0].set_title('Three plots\n')
axarr[0].set_ylabel('A')
axarr[1].set_ylabel('B')
axarr[2].set_ylabel('C')
axarr[0].set_ylim(ymin=0.001,ymax=max(A_lst)*1.10)
axarr[1].set_ylim(ymin=0.001,ymax=max(B_lst)*1.10)
axarr[2].set_ylim(ymin=0.001,ymax=max(B_lst)*1.10)
axarr[0].grid()
axarr[1].grid()
axarr[2].grid()
rects1 = axarr[0].bar(ind, A_lst, width, color='r',  linewidth=1,alpha=0.8, label=cr_lst)
rects2 = axarr[1].bar(ind, B_lst, width, color='y', linewidth=1,alpha=0.8, label=cr_lst)
rects3 = axarr[2].bar(ind, C_lst, width, color='blue',  linewidth=1, alpha=0.8, label=cr_lst) 
plt.savefig("ByC.png")
```

I'd like to have the labels shown on the x-axis.

Comment: I am not sure  but did u use set_xlable into code

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami I should have been more clear - I want to label each of the bar along each x axis.

Comment: A reproducible example would nice. Your code is missing several definitions and therefore does not run...

Comment: Thanks for updating the code. Do you mean that the labels should by __inside__ the bars and not as xtick lables?

Comment: @ Ideally each label appears under each bar for each of the three axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the labels under each bar on every axes:

```
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
cr_lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
x = range(len(cr_lst)) # the x locations for the groups
A_lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B_lst = [2, 2, 6, 7]
C_lst = [8, 8, 6, 7]
f, axarr = plt.subplots(3, sharex=False)
axarr[0].set_title('Three plots\n')
axarr[0].set_ylabel('A')
axarr[1].set_ylabel('B')
axarr[2].set_ylabel('C')
axarr[0].set_ylim(ymin=0.001,ymax=max(A_lst)*1.10)
axarr[1].set_ylim(ymin=0.001,ymax=max(B_lst)*1.10)
axarr[2].set_ylim(ymin=0.001,ymax=max(B_lst)*1.10)
axarr[0].grid()
axarr[1].grid()
axarr[2].grid()
rects1 = axarr[0].bar(x, A_lst, width, color='r', align='center', linewidth=1,alpha=0.8)
rects2 = axarr[1].bar(x, B_lst, width, color='y', align='center', linewidth=1,alpha=0.8)
rects3 = axarr[2].bar(x, C_lst, width, color='blue', align='center', linewidth=1, alpha=0.8) 
for ax in axarr:
    ax.set_xticks(x)
    ax.set_xticklabels(cr_lst)

plt.savefig("ByC.png")
```

Note that `share=False` in `plt.subplots`. If you set it to `True` it hides all other labels but the lowest ax.

Also note the use of `align='center'` in `.bar()`.

This yields:
[image]